# Product with minimum and maximum price (data is read from a text file)

Tags: java, arrays, io, inputstream, filestream

Input file : 
sugar;1.2;30

milk;4.5;100

grain;3.2;200

In the output file I have to print the product with minimum and maximum price(milk and sugar).
My program prints the product with the maximum price but for the minimum price it prints grain.

**Main class:**

```
public class Lab3 
{ 
    public static void main (String[ ] args) throws IOException
    { 
        double max=0, min=10000000;

        Product p_min=new Product("",0.0,0);
        Product p_max=new Product("",0.0,0);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new      FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Timotei\\Desktop\\in.txt")));
        PrintStream out=new PrintStream(new  FileOutputStream("C://Users//Timotei//Desktop//out.txt"));
        String line;          
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null)
        {

            String[] array=line.split(";");
            String name=array[0];
            double price=Double.valueOf(array[1]);
            int quantity=Integer.valueOf(array[2]);
            if(price>max)
            {
                max=price;
                p_max=new Product(name,price,quantity); 
            }
            if(price<min)
            {
                min=price;
                p_min=new Product(name,price,quantity);
            }
        }
        out.println("Product with maximum price is:"+p_max);
        System.out.println("Product with maximum price is:"+p_max); 
        System.out.println("Product with minimum price is:"+p_min);
        out.println("Product with minimum price is:"+p_min);
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Product class:

```
public class Product 
{
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;     
    public Product(String name, double price, int quantity)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.price=price;
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }
    public Product(Product p)
    {
        p.name=name;
        p.price=price;
        p.quantity=quantity;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return name+" which has the price "+price+" and is present in a quantity of "+quantity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace this :

```
if(price<max)
    min=price;
```

by

```
if(price<min)
    min=price;
```

Comment: And indent your code better, structure is not clear. Try to make you usage of brackets more consistent to increase readibility : use them always or never, but always follow the same rule.

Comment: I have updated the code , it still doesn't work. At the output it prints grain as product with minimum price.

Comment: There should be no "else" but two distinct if blocks. First entry of your file is sugar, it should be counted both as p_max and p_min until we meet milk.

Comment: As an exercize, please re-indent as clearly as possible.

Comment: In that case, you can accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: I am new and I don't have 15 reputation :( . Once I will have I will upvote it :D

Comment: done :) And you don't need to update your question when it is solved.